# Inserting an image in plain TeX

Tags: graphics, plain-tex

I used the OzTeX implementation of TeX, also I used to typeset my docs in plain TeX, not LaTeX for me, so I had no problem to insert an image using the OzTeX, now I'm back to TeX docs, am using the TeXWorks frontend, but I can't insert an `.eps` image file, it seems the `\includegraphics` macro its only for LaTeX, so I can't use it, any idea on how to insert an image when using plain TeX?

Answer (score 19):

By far the easiest approach here is to use `miniltx` to allow you to use LaTeX's `graphics` package with plain TeX:

```
\input miniltx %
\input graphicx.sty %
\includegraphics{<filename>}
\bye
```

or

```
\input graphicx.tex %
\includegraphics{<filename>}
\bye
```

(See comments for the minor differences here.)

The only thing you will need to watch is that TeXworks is designed around a PDF-based workflow. Thus you will need to convert your `.eps` files to `.pdf` format using `epstopdf` and then use pdfTeX in TeXworks. (In LaTeX, there is now automatic conversion method from `.eps` to `.pdf` files, but this does not apply to plain TeX.)

Comment: Is there a difference between this and simply `\input graphicx.tex` (no `miniltx`)?

Comment: @AlanMunn I've simply gone with 'what I know'. A quick look at `graphicx.tex` shows it loads `miniltx`, adds a default driver line (`dvips`) and tidies up the catcode of `@` using `\resetatcatcode`. The last point might make it very slightly preferable, but it's not a bit difference.

Comment: @JosephWright Also the automatic conversion from EPS to PDF for pdfTeX will work, if package `epstopdf-base` is loaded after `graphicx`: `\input miniltx \def\Gin@driver{pdftex.def} \input graphicx.sty \input epstopdf-base \resetatcatcode`

Answer (score 17):

You can use the simple `epsf` package which is designed for plain TeX:

```
\input epsf
%optional \epsfxsize=dimen or \epsfysize=dimen
\epsfbox{filename.eps}
```

Answer (score 15):

For `pdftex` users the `\pdfximage` approach might seem appealing. The `\pdfximage` command creates an image object. The dimensions can be controlled in a similar way to a rule, i.e.

```
\pdfximage width ... height ... depth ... <general text>
```

where `<general text>` is the file name. (`\pdfximage` has many more parameters which can be looked up in the [`pdftex` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/pdftex/manual/pdftex-a.pdf). For advanced things such as adjusting the bounding box also consult the manual.)

Still, `\pdfximage` only creates an *object* but does not insert anything yet. Therefore `\pdfrefximage` has to be used.  The command

```
\pdfrefximage <integer>
```

places a whatsit including the image stored in the object referred to by `<integer>` in the output at shipout. In principle one could output the number corresponding to each image object, write them down and then later do, e.g. `\pdfrefximage3`. This is tedious and error prone, though. That's why there is `\pdflastximage` which is a count register always containing the number of the last `\pdfximage`, so including an image can be boiled down the following code

```
\pdfximage width 3cm {example-image-a.pdf}
\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage
\bye
```

**TL;DR: See the code right above this line**

Answer (score 11):

The `\inspic` macro is provided by `opmac.tex`. You can set `\picwidth` register or `\picheight` register (or both, but the aspect is probably deformed in such case) and you can type `\inspic file.jpg` or `\inspic file.pdf` etc.

```
\input opmac

\picwidth=3cm \inspic file.png
\bye
```

You can look into `opmac.tex` to get the ispiration how this macro is defined at primitive level:

```
\def\inspic #1 {\hbox{%
    \pdfximage \ifdim\picwidth=0pt \else width\picwidth\fi 
               \ifdim\picheight=0pt \else height\picheight\fi {\picdir#1}%
    \pdfrefximage\pdflastximage}}
```

This works in pdfTeX. When XeTeX is used then the additional `opmac-xetex.tex` macro file is loaded and the `\inspic` macro is redefined:

```
\def\inspic #1 {\hbox{\def\tmp##1.pdf##2\relax{%
   \ifnum\strcmp{##2}{.pdf}=0 \XeTeXpdffile \else \XeTeXpicfile \fi}%
   \lowercase{\tmp #1}.pdf\relax \picdir#1
       \ifdim\picwidth=0pt \else width\picwidth\fi
       \ifdim\picheight=0pt \else height\picheight\fi}}
```

The main complication of this code is the fact that XeTeX needs to use different primitive for PDF including (`\XeTeXpdffile`) and different for another bitmap images (\XeTeXpicfile`).