# Image inclusion in TeX (not LaTeX)

Tags: graphics, plain-tex

I am using **TeX** (**not LaTeX**). I want to print our company logo in TeX Generated Invoice. Kindly help.

Comment: Perhaps post the logo or a link to an image of it.

Comment: The `insbox` package light be helpful as it's a `generic` package, that you load with `\input{insbox.tex}`.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63789/inserting-an-image-in-plain-tex perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `pdftex` inserting images is as easy as

```
\pdfximage width 3cm {example-image-a.pdf}
\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage
\bye
```