# How does wrapfig internally work?

Tags: package-writing, wrapfig

[wrapfig](https://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) is a LaTeX package designed to make it possible to let text flow around images. I am acquainted with the documentation, which was written with the needs of an end user in mind. But how does wrapfig work internally?

The basic procedure (make whitespace for the image, use the driver to place it) is conceptually [clear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308322/how-does-including-graphics-in-tex-work) to me. But I am curious:

1. What is the "big picture" of wrapfig's low-level method of operation?
2. (How) Does wrapfig somehow determine the hyphenation points at which the floating text shall break?
3. Is it correct that wrapfig currently is not able to have text on both sides, such that the text continues on the other side? (Think of the image placed in the middle of a column.)

Sadly, I am way too bad in TeX to be able to answer my questions myself using wrapfig's source code and "Random implementation notes" within the documentation.

Comment: The big deal with wrapfig is its ability to wrap more than one paragraph, for which it uses \everypar.  If you only need to wrap one paragraph, there are many different ways to do it, including shapepar which can put a gap into the center.

Answer (score 17):

TeX has a `\parshape` primitive that specifies a number of special lines before a paragraph then for each line, a pair of (left margin, line width) pairs. The last pair is used on all following lines, so

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textwidth{6cm}
\begin{document}
\newlength\shortline
\shortline=\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm

\parshape 4
0pt  \shortline
0pt  \shortline
0pt  \shortline
0pt  \textwidth
One two three four five six seven.
Red blue green yellow white black.
One two three four five six seven.
Red blue green yellow white black.
One two three four five six seven.
Red blue green yellow white black.

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

So basically `wrapfig` sets the figure in a box to find the default length to cut and the number of lines to cut so as to produce the above, then it drops in the figure in the space:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textwidth{6cm}
\newlength\shortline

\begin{document}

\shortline=\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm

\parshape 4
0pt  \shortline
0pt  \shortline
0pt  \shortline
0pt  \textwidth
\noindent\smash{\rlap{\hspace{\textwidth}\llap{%
\hspace{2mm}%
\rule[-.8cm]{1.8cm}{1cm}}}}%
\indent
One two three four five six seven.
Red blue green yellow white black.
One two three four five six seven.
Red blue green yellow white black.
One two three four five six seven.
Red blue green yellow white black.

\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]

The clever part of the package is detecting if you need more than one paragraph and if so constructing a new shorter `\parshape` for the later ones.

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textwidth{6cm}
\newlength\shortline

\begin{document}
\sloppy

\shortline=\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm

\parshape 4
0pt  \shortline
0pt  \shortline
0pt  \shortline
0pt  \textwidth
\noindent\smash{\rlap{\hspace{\textwidth}\llap{%
\hspace{2mm}%
\rule[-.8cm]{1.8cm}{1cm}}}}%
\indent
One two three four five six seven.
Red blue green


\parshape 2
0pt  \shortline
0pt  \textwidth
Yellow white black.
One two three four five six seven.
Red blue green yellow white black.
One two three four five six seven.
Red blue green yellow white black.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been using LaTeX for sometime now and there's so many things I still don't know. I guess it's going to be forever ongoing process since it's begun.

Comment: Is the machinery that extends `\parshape` to multiple paragraphs available outside of `wrapfig`, for arbitrary paragraph shapes? Sounds like it would make a nice package on its own..

Comment: @schtandard not as far as I know. I looked at it in detail once for a question on this site which merged it with the parshape for a `lettrine` drop-cap `\parshape`

Comment: @schtandard https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119688/lettrine-and-wrapfig/121555#121555

Comment: Too bad. Thanks for the link.